# Метаклассы Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста для чего нужны метаклассы. В учебнике 'A Byte of Python' написано для того чтобы запретить создание новых методов в основном классе, если я конечно правильно понял, например перед методом мы пишем @abstractmethod. И для чего это нужно (запрещать создание новых методов)? Если я не так понял - пожалуйста подскажите для чего нужны метеклассы в Python?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005878/what-are-python-metaclasses-useful-for

Answer (score 3):

Классы в python, как и остальные сущности, являются объектами, экземплярами какого-то класса. Обычно это класс `type` (который, кстати, тоже является своим собственным экземпляром)

```
class A:
    pass

print(type(A)) # <class 'type'>
```

`type` в данном случае является метаклассом, классом для класса, и его можно указать явно, хоть в этом нет необходимости, он и без этого является метаклассом по умолчнию

```py
class A(metaclass=type):
    pass
```

Также в качестве метакласса может быть использован любой другой потомок класса `type`

```
class M(type):
    pass

class A(metaclass=M):
    pass

print(type(A)) # <class '__main__.M'>
```

И даже не обязательно потомок `type`, и даже не обязательно класс, а любой вызываемй объект, которому будут передано имя создаваемого класса, а также его предки и его словарь. Правда класс, определенный с таким метаклассом, может вообще не быть классом.

Таким образом можно, например, определить (или переопределить) методы, которые можно будет вызывать от имени класса.

```
class M(type):
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<my class '{self.__name__}'>"

class A(metaclass=M):
    pass

class B:
    pass

print(A) # <my class 'A'>
print(B) # <class '__main__.B'>
```

### Upd:

Пример класса-одиночки, имеющего ровно один экземпляр. При попытке создать новый экземпляр будет возвращен ранее созданный.

```py
class SingletonMeta(type):
    instances = {}

    def __call__(self):
        if self not in self.instances:
            self.instances[self] = super().__call__()

        return self.instances[self]

class A(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    pass

class B:
    pass

a1 = A()
a2 = A()
b1 = B()
b2 = B()
print(a1 is a2) # True
print(b1 is b2) # False
```

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ, но немного нужно вникнуть мне в это т.к.  я новичок в программировании.

Comment: Я тем более первый раз вижу метод __call__. Я почитал только что про него.

Comment: Я не могу понять какой класс собственный в Вашем примере?

Comment: @Evgeniy немного дополнил ответ. метод `__call__` вызывается, когда к экземпляру обращаются как к функции, пытаясь его вызвать. То же самое происходит и при создании экземпляра класса. В вашем случае чтобы запретить создание экземпляра нужно в метаклассе выбрасывать исключение в методе `__call__` или возвращать какой-то заготовленный заранее экземпляр вместо создания нового. Вообще это достаточно продвинутая тема для новичка в программировании

Comment: @Evgeniy Говоря про собственный, я имел в виду, что класс `type` является экземпляром класса `type`. Т.е. своим собственным экземпляром. Это небольшая магия python, которую не получится реализовать средствами языка.

Comment: Ладно. Спасибо. Хороший ответ. Я конечно понял не всё, но надеюсь вникнуть, тем более если Вы говорите что для новичка эта тема продвинутая. Но некоторые вещи понял. :) Удачи.

Comment: @Evgeniy настолько продвинутая, что большинство программистов с ней не сталкиваются. Еще немного дополнил ответ, ближе к теме вопроса.